# What is a phrase that would mean that individuals are each so unique, that their uniqueness becomes ubiquitous?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am looking for a phrase that would indicate that teens, despite their longing to be seen as *sui generis,* are indeed unique, but that they are all so unique, that that uniqueness becomes commonplace, and therefore not special anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the terms meaning "unique" along with the word "ubiquitous". For example: "ubiquitously distinct"

> "Teens are such ubiquitously distinct individuals that their
>   uniqueness often gets lost in their commonplace status."

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ubiquitous

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/commonplace